# Appbundle build failure

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    // Replace the line below with your desired error handling mechanism
    println "Flutter SDK location not found. Define the location with 'flutter.sdk' in the local.properties file."
    return
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cordless"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
            def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
            keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    // Add your other dependencies here
}

//This is my build.gradle file
```

**Error:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\vidhy\cordless\android\app\build.gradle' line: 53
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           2,426ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1.

I got this problem while building an App bundle of my flutter project . I have given my gradle file and the error.Is there any ways to fix this.i have al ready tried to fix this but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because Gradle is unable to find the `storeFile` at the specified path. So first check the `storFile` is located at the place you've defined in `key.properties` and `key.properties` file is located at android/key.properties[image]

If it exists there use the below code

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    // Replace the line below with your desired error handling mechanism
    println "Flutter SDK location not found. Define the location with 'flutter.sdk' in the local.properties file."
    return
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cordless"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    // Add your other dependencies here
}
```

If you get error at line no 30 or 31 it means `key.properties` file isn't located at right destination.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I am getting problems with the 31 line but I have verified your answer , my key.properties file is within the android folder.my storefile is also located at the specified destination.can you please help me.